# Git-Extensions : patch does not apply, error code 100644

Tags: git, windows-10, file-permissions, git-extensions

I'm working on a C# project, my versioning system is based on GIT and I would like to check in some minor changes in my software using GIT-extensions, using "Stage selected line(s)". I have done this before and it was working fine. Now, however, I'm getting the error message "patch does not apply" in a messagebox.

I see two possible problems:

1. either something's wrong with the small change itself.
2. either something's wrong with the entire file (investigation of error code 100644).

### 1._Investigation of the small change.

Hereby some typical examples (in one case I just try to stage the new (green) line, in the second I try to stage the new (green) and the deleted (red) line:

Example1:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
error: patch failed: <Directory>/Filename.cs:105
error: <Directory>/Filename.cs: patch does not apply


diff --git a/<Directory>/Filename.cs b/<Directory>/Filename.cs
index 8947eb9..8be5ca9 100644
--- a/<Directory>/Filename.cs
+++ b/<Directory>/Filename.cs
@@ -105,14 +105,15 @@
                 {
                     using (var database = ...())
                     {
                         log.Debug($"Information recognised ...");
+                        log.Trace($"Information recognised ...");
                         ...
--
Git Extensions 3.5.4.12724
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Example 2:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
error: patch failed: <Directory>/Filename.cs:105
error: <Directory>/Filename.cs: patch does not apply


diff --git a/<Directory>/Filename.cs b/<Directory>/Filename.cs
index 8947eb9..8be5ca9 100644
--- a/<Directory>/Filename.cs
+++ b/<Directory>/Filename.cs
@@ -105,14 +105,14 @@
                 {
                     using (var database = ...())
                     {
-                        log.Debug($"Information recognised ...");
+                        log.Trace($"Information recognised ...");
                         ...
--
Git Extensions 3.5.4.12724
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

As you can see, I'm trying to replace `log.Debug` by `log.Trace`.

For your information, I have also tried to do the same thing on larger parts of code, but the problem persists.

### 2._Investigation of the entire file

As far as the "errorcode" is concerned (100644): according to some Google search results this is related to file permissions, which are not very straightforward in Windows, so I have used my Ubuntu WSL app for showing directory/file permissions on my Windows-10 computer, this is the result:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 scampsd scampsd 42034 Mar 29 15:26 Filename.cs
drwxrwxrwx 1 scampsd scampsd  4096 Mar 29 15:26 .
```

Those results are similar for other files in that directory. I have no idea if this is correct or not.

Does anybody know what I can do?
I'm using GIT-extensions as an interactive Windows tool, I'm not familiar with commandline GIT.

**Edit 1:**
I have just tried `chmod 644 Filename.cs`, but the file permissions say equal.

**Edit2:**
Instead of using my WSL Ubuntu, I asked `ls -ltra` using GIT bash, this the result:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 DDM 1049089 42034 Mar 29 15:26 Filename.cs
drwxr-xr-x 1 DDM 1049089     0 Mar 29 15:26 ./
```

In top of this, I tried to stage the entire file, and that worked fine.

**Edit3:**
According to the answer on [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1713604), I have launched:

```
stat -c '%a' Filename.cs
644
```

So, the errorcode `100644` means that the file's properties are `100644` which are somewhere wrong, but I have no idea what it should be instead.

**Edit4:**
Git version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.31.1.windows.1
```

Comment: " I just try to stage": so "git add". Can you try "`git add --chmod=+x` -- Yourfile"?

Comment: @VonC: I don't know how to do this, I'm working with GIT-Extensions as an interactive Windows applications, I don't know how to work with GIT in commandline mode.

Comment: @VonC: as I mentioned in my edit, I have tried to modify file permissions, but I failed.

Comment: `100664` is the file's mode in octal, not an error code. `1` means it's a regular file and `644` means read+write for owner, read for group and others.

Comment: @Dominique I would still try the `git add --chmod=+x` in command line (through Git for Windows: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: @VonC: I'm not sure, but I believe that `git add` or `git add --chmod=+x` is staging the entire file, and this seems to be working fine. However I'm having a problem, not while staging the entire file (which is working fine), but just staging some lines.

Comment: @Dominique OK. It was just for testing if the associated chmod was relevant or not in your scenario.

Comment: @VonC: well, it just might: on the internet I have seen some commands, looking like `git <do_something> patchname.patch`. I imagine that, for my case, it might come down to `git add --chmod=+x patchname.patch`, but then the question is: is there a way to "record" my GIT Extensions' "Stage selected line(s)" into a `patchname.patch` file?

Comment: The message "patch does not apply" simply means that the instructions ("change line 105 as shown, and the context *around* line 105 must match as shown as well") don't match the actual file. Take a look at the file, at line 105. What's on line 105? What is on the surrounding lines? Can you mechanically apply that patch "by hand"? If so, did you have to make a *different* change?